# Is it appropriate for an expert witness to meet and have dinner with the legal team? Do you need to disclose that in a report?

Tags: united-states, testimony

See 0:08 in ["Amber Heard Perpetrated Intimate Partner Violence Towards Johnny Depp" Says Psychologist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVZIttwymLY)

Is it appropriate to meet and have dinner with the legal team as an expert and does the expert need to disclose that in a report? I thought it was weird that the expert had dinner when there can be the appearance of a conflict of interest.

Comment: If the legal team is already paying the expert to testify, I don't see how eating dinner together meaningfully changes the conflict analysis.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is common for a legal team, particularly in a major case, to meet with a potential expert witness before hiring that witness.. It is also common for the team to meet with such an expert as testimony is being prepared. Food is often served at such meetings.

Comment: A priori this makes total sense but do you have any a posteriori source? Not sure what would really be a source but I did eventually find a source for my [jewish family guy joke](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96796/whats-up-with-answering-questions-with-questions-in-this-joke-from-family-guy) Q&A

Comment: @BCLC
 I have never heard or read of anyone objection to an expert witness on such grounds, I can't cite case law. I am not sure what sort of source you might be looking for.